# Haskell String to Maybe List

Tags: haskell

```
readSquareTransition :: String -> Maybe [SquareTurn]
readSquareTransition [] = Just []
readSquareTransition (x:xs) = case x of
      'L' -> Just (L : readSquareTransition xs)
      'R' -> Just (R : readSquareTransition xs)
       _      -> Nothing
```

I want to get Just [L,L,R,R]. But looks like i failed :( Here is the error message!

```
src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:231:24:
Couldn't match expected type ‘[SquareTurn]’
            with actual type ‘Maybe [SquareTurn]’
In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘readSquareTransition xs’
In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely
  ‘(L : readSquareTransition xs)’

src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:232:24:
Couldn't match expected type ‘[SquareTurn]’
            with actual type ‘Maybe [SquareTurn]’
In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘readSquareTransition xs’
In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely
  ‘(R : readSquareTransition xs)’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modular way of doing this would be to define `readSquareTurn` first which defines how to turn a `Char` into a single `SquareTurn` (with the possibility of failure):

```
readSquareTurn :: Char -> Maybe SquareTurn
readSquareTurn x = case x of
  'L' -> Just L
  'R' -> Just R
  _   -> Nothing
```

and then use `mapM :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe [b]` to process the whole `String` like so:

```
readSquareTransition :: String -> Maybe [SquareTurn]
readSquareTransition = mapM readSquareTurn
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
'L' -> Just (L : readSquareTransition xs)
'R' -> Just (R : readSquareTransition xs)
```

to this

```
'L' -> fmap (L :) $ readSquareTransition xs
'R' -> fmap (R :) $ readSquareTransition xs
```

The problem is that readSquareTransition returns a `Maybe [SquareTurn]`, so you can't apply `(:)` to it (`(:)` requires a List).  `fmap` however lets you apply into the `Just` (while preserving a `Nothing`).

Comment: You'd have to drop the `Just` though: `readSquareTransition` already returns a Maybe something.

Comment: You should add parentheses around `readSquareTransition xs`, or a `$` before it, or use the infix `(<$>)` instead of `fmap`.